# bash - fail when splitting a string, but zsh is working

Tags: bash

Bash newbie here. I have a string in the variable `IN` and I want to split it into an array when the delimiter `;` is found. Reading different stack exchange answers ([this one specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)), I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IN="12;25;365"
IFS=";" read -r -a ARR <<< "$IN"
echo $ARR
```

The output is `12`. Interestingly, if I try the following commands in zsh:

```
IN="12;25;365"
IFS=";" read -r -A ARR <<< "$IN"
echo $ARR
```

The output will be `12 25 365`.

What am I doing wrong in the bash script? I need that working in bash...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash requires using `${ARR[@]}` or `${ARR[*]}` to display all elements of array.

For further reading: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script

Modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IN="12;25;365"
IFS=";" read -r -a ARR <<< "$IN"
echo ${ARR[@]}
```